# Selenium->Automation planning->How to Execute Majority of the TestCases at a time?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

iam learning selenium inorder to reproduce it on my application.so,please help me by answering my questions.1)how to execute bulk of testcases at a time by using automation tool (selenium 2)?)how to start my application to test with automation tool selenium rc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use selenium API, you need to download the needed .jar files from [here](http://seleniumhq.org/download/)

Once you add the needed .jar files to your projects classpath, you are ready to start doing testing.

Here a very simple hello world application example that can help you understand selenium tests. (As you see there is no call to main or anithing similar, the tests will run automatically when the application is launched)

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;    
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class HelloSeleniumTest extends TestCase {

    private Selenium browser;

    public void setUp() {

        browser = new DefaultSelenium("localhost",

            4444, "*firefox", "http://www.google.com");

        browser.start();

    }



    public void testGoogle() {

        browser.open("http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en");

        browser.type("q", "hello world");

        browser.click("btnG");

        browser.waitForPageToLoad("5000");

        assertEquals("hello world - Google Search", browser.getTitle());

    }



    public void tearDown() {

        browser.stop();

    }

}
```

Before you run the app, you should start the RC server from the console. It is very simple, just:

1- Go to the Selenium-Server folder using the console (The place where are the files that you downloaded)

2- execute java -jar selenium-server.jar

Once is running, go back to your programming IDE and run the application

Also you have the possibility of downloading the Selenium plugin for firefox, that will create for you the java code when you navigate the pages so your testing will go faster.
This is how it looks like:

[image]

If something still unclear, visit this [link](http://helloopensource.pbworks.com/w/page/17656661/SeleniumRC_JavaClient), it is very well explained.

Answer (score 0):

Download [demo with sample test](http://www.infostretch.com/QA/selenium-framework.php) and try with it